# Debugging JNI Code on my Nexus S

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

How can I debug JNI code on my device! I enable debugging and Im able to successfully set break points in Java and able to debug using Eclipse.

But when it comes to my JNI C/C++ code I can't debug! Eclipse doesn't get no feedback on the breakpoints that I set.

Please help!

ps: Im using Android SDK 2.3.4, NDK r5b on MacOS Snow Leopard

Comment: You can always start by including <android/log.h> to allow use of similar functions to the Log java class. This way you can at least get output in logcat.

Comment: Also found this with the magic of google... http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php if you use Eclipse. There is also information on using ndk-gdb in the documentation included with the ndk.

Comment: I've seen this one but its only for debugging with the emulator... I need to debug C/C++ code on the device.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this tutorials:

[Using Eclipse for Android C/C++ Development](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/)

[Using Eclipse for Android C/C++ Debugging](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/)